# How to determine iglargest stable bitmap dimensions

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

I am working on an app that allows a user to draw within a confined canvas on a bitmap. Each drawing is created on a separate bitmap, which is then added to the main bitmap in the onDraw() method. This main bitmap needs to be larger than the screen dimensions so the user has plenty of room to draw a detailed scene. As such I also gave users the ability to pan/zoom on this main bitmap.

I noticed that this main bitmap size affects the performance of the device's drawing ability. The dimension have statically set at this point is 3000X3000, which works fine for my Galaxy 10.1 Pro tablet, but is VERY choppy on my low end Galaxy phone. This app is not meant to be used on phones, but the issue is still the same: how do I dynamically determine the dimensions for the main bitmap so that performance is consistent across devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what the screen size is, do this. Docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29)

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Then you can use that information to resize the image.

You can set o.inJustDecodeBounds = true to get the image sizes without loading the image. If the image is to big, you can resize it. Example code below.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

Uri uri = getImageUri(path);
InputStream in = null;
try {
final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

// Decode image size
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
in.close();



int scale = 1;
while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) > 
      IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
   scale++;
}
Log.d(TAG, "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", 
   orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

Bitmap b = null;
in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
if (scale > 1) {
    scale--;
    // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
    // larger than target
    o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inSampleSize = scale;
    b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

    // resize to desired dimensions
    int height = b.getHeight();
    int width = b.getWidth();
    Log.d(TAG, "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ",
       height: " + height);

    double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
            / (((double) width) / height));
    double x = (y / height) * width;

    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x, 
       (int) y, true);
    b.recycle();
    b = scaledBitmap;

    System.gc();
} else {
    b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
}
in.close();

Log.d(TAG, "bitmap size - width: " +b.getWidth() + ", height: " + 
   b.getHeight());
return b;
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
return null;
}
```